# How to split a string with double quotes " as the delimiter?

Tags: java, scala

I tried splitting like this-

```
tableData.split("\\"")
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you tried to escape it same way as you would escape `|` which is `"\\|"`. But difference between `|` and `"` is that

- `|` is metacharacter in regex engine (it represents OR operator)
- `"` is metacharacter in Java language in string literal (it represents start/end of the string)

To escape any String metacharacter (like `"`) you need to place before it other String metacharacter responsible for escaping which is `\`<sup>1</sup>. So to create String which would contain `"` like `this is "quote"` you would need to write it as

```
String s = "this is \"quote\"";
//                  ^^     ^^ these represent " literal, not end of string
```

Same idea is applied if we would like to create `\` literal (we would need to escape it by placing another `\` before it). For instance if we would want to create string representing `c:\foo\bar` we would need to write it as

```
String s = "c:\\foo\\bar";
//            ^^    ^^    these will represent \ literal
```

So as you see `\` is used to escape metacharacters (make them simple literals).
This character is used in Java language for Strings, but it also is used in regex engine to escape its [metacharacters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special):
`\`, `^`, `$`, `.`, `|`, `?`, `*`, `+`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `{`.

If you would like to create regex which will match `[` character you will need to use regex `\[` but String representing this regex in Java needs to be written as

```
String leftBracketRegex = "\\[";
//                         ^^ - Remember what was said earlier? 
//                              To create \ literal in String we need to escape it
```

So to split on `[` we would need to invoke `split("\\[")` because regex representing `[` is `\[` which needs to be written as `"\\["` in Java.

Since `"` is not special character in regex but it is special in String we need to escape it only in string literal by writing it as

```
split("\"");
```

---

1) `\` is also used to create other characters line separators `\n`, tab `\t`. It can also be used to create Unicode characters like `\uXXXX` where `XXXX` is index of character in Unicode table in hexadecimal form.

Answer (score 4):

You have escaped the `\` by putting in `\` twice, try

```
tableData.split("\"")
```

*Why does this happen?*
A backslash escapes the following character. Since the next character is another backslash, the second backslash will be escaped, thus the doublequote won't.
Your resulting escaped string is `\"`, where it should really be just `"`.

*Edit:*
Also keep in mind, that `String.split()` interprets its pattern parameter as a regular expression, which has several special characters, which have to be escaped in the resulting string.
So if you want split by a `.`(which is a special regex character), you need to specify it as `String.split("\\.")`. The first backslash escapes the escaping function of the second backlash and would result in `"\."`.

In case of regex characters you could also just use `Pattern.quote();` to escape your desired delimiter, but this is far out of the scope the question orignally had.

Comment: When I split using the delimiter  =  I gave as  tableData.split("\\=") . What is the difference between " and =

Comment: @Goku__ "*When I split using the delimiter `=` I gave as `tableData.split("\\=")`*" then you are overdoing it. Simple `split("=")` is enough since `=` is not regex metacharacter so you don't need to escape it with ``\`` (which in String needs to be written as `"\\"`).

Comment: @Goku__ don't use escaping if you don't need it. `"` is a special case, since it's a special character as it marks string literals, therefore you have to escape it, if you want to use `"` discretely. `=`isn't special, so just use it without escaping.

Answer (score 2):

Try with single backslash `\`

```
  tableData.split("\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this by escaping `"` with single backslash `\` :

```
tableData.split("\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping properly. The snippet code will not even compile because of it. The correct way to do it is

```
tableData.split("\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

A single backslash will do the trick.

Like this:

```
tableData.split("\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually split without the backward slash. You only have to use single quote

```
tableData.split('"');
```